# how to read a txt file in php

Tags: php

I have a data diractory in my server and there is many text file like

```
text1.txt
abc.txt
def.txt
```

now i need to read a specific line that contain a specific word like (emp_name) from each file and echo full line in my php project.
how to do this any help appreciated Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know in advance what the file names are, or does that change?

Comment: there is many way to read a line but i need to read a line which contain a specific word

Comment: ya i know the file names

Comment: Have you put any effort to finding the solution before posting it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your direction should be like this:

```
1. firstly open the file , through fopen()
2. then by file_get_contents() or fread() to get the content 
3. then search for the desired word in the file
```

**edit:**
do like this:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("input.txt"); //read the file
if(strpos($data,"str_to_find")==false){ //check if string exists in file
echo "str not found";
}
else 
echo "str found";

?>
```

Comment: pls post the code example

Comment: your code just find the string i have given but i need to print full line which hold the string

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code:

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r')
```

If you want to read word by word

check [this](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=982) out

[This](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileread.php) is too